# How to prevent certain websites in my browser

Tags: 12.04, firefox

I am using Firefox 33.0 on my Ubuntu 12.04 but apparently I cannot prevent a website from being opened in the browser, is there a way to do that, like using some system configurations?.
What about preventing a website permanently on the system regardless of the browser being used?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parental controls with different settings for different users](http://askubuntu.com/questions/647/parental-controls-with-different-settings-for-different-users)

Comment: Sorry it is duplicated,  http://askubuntu.com/questions/647/parental-controls-with-different-settings-for-different-users I may need to use an add-ons!.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to restrict access to adult content?](http://askubuntu.com/q/158572/325633); see also [Modifying /etc/hosts does not have an effect](http://askubuntu.com/q/3249/325633), [How to block specific domains in the hosts file?](http://askubuntu.com/q/150135/325633), and [How to block any site?](http://askubuntu.com/q/491393/325633)

Answer (score 1):

One option for you is to block the websites through **DNS**. On Ubuntu, you may follow [the instructions on this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/23164). You may need to clear your DNS cache from Ubuntu to make sure all DNS query are executed again, thus creating a new cache without the blocked websites. This will not prevent the access to the website itself, but it'll make impossible for your browser to translate www.exemple.com into 67.23.11.1, for instance.

You may apply those rules on your router to further improve the block.

Answer (score 0):

I read the dupe answer link but it didn't mention the free account at Opendns.org. [Free personal account.](https://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/parental-controls/opendns-familyshield/)

By pointing your DNS at their DNS servers, you can block categories of websites, individual websites as you find them, log attempts to get to blocked websites, etc.

> When you set up OpenDNS Home on your router, your settings take effect
>   across everything on your home network. In addition to computers, this
>   includes your kids’ Xbox, Playstation, Wii, DS, iPad, and even their
>   iPhone.